# Empty recycling bin from command line

Tags: windows, command-line

How to empty recycling bin from command line in Windows XP?

Answer (score 6):

As I posted elsewhere, I use `rmdir /q /s C:\Recycler` to empty the Recycle Bin. If you have multiple drives, then replace C: with that drive letter.

Answer (score 4):

[Instructions are here](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/639485-how-do-empty-recycle-bin.html)

First, you need to create file called something like EmptyBin.reg like so:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\Recycle Bin]
"StateFlags0001"=dword:00000002
```

Now, you create a batch (*.bat) file with the following:

```
regedit /s EmptyBin.reg
cleanmgr /sagerun:1
```

Run that batch file from the command line to empty your bin.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. It clears some system caches, but it leaves recycling bin untouched :/

Comment: @Dan, Weird, wouldn't the `rmdir` solution above work fine?

Answer (score 2):

while

> rd /s /q %systemdrive%\$RECYCLE.BIN

will delete the $RECYCLE.BIN folder from the system drive, which is usually c:,
one should consider deleting it from any other available partitions since there's an hidden $RECYCLE.BIN folder in any partition in local and external drives (but not in removable drives, like USB flash drive, which don't have a $RECYCLE.BIN folder).
For example, I installed a program in d:, in order to delete the files it moved to the Recycle Bin I should run:

> rd /s /q d:\$RECYCLE.BIN

More information available at Stack Overflow at [how to empty recyclebin through command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238953/how-to-empty-recyclebin-through-command-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

The recycle bin is just another folder; you should be able to delete the files from [C:\RECYCLER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recycle_Bin_(Windows)#Physical_storage_locations) to achieve the same effect as emptying the recycle bin from the GUI.

Comment: The recycle bin is not a simple folder at all, but rather a virtual one. It's true that its contents are stored in the "Recycler" or "$Recycle.bin" directories on each drive root, but I wouldn't blindly delete their contents. It's probably OK, but it would feel like a dirty hack. :o)

Answer (score 0):

I can use VBScript for this:

```
Dim objShell,objFolder,objItem,fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(10)
For Each objItem In objFolder.Items
  fso.DeleteFile objItem
Next
```