# Clear Recycler on C: with Command Line

Tags: command-line, batch, recycle-bin

I'm looking for a simple Batch which clears all files/folders in my Recycler on Volume C: and under Windows 7 x64.

```
DEL C:\Recycler\*.*
```

I thought this is a good try, but no success.

The way over `cleanmgr /sagerun:1` is NOT what i'm looking for. (already posted here)

[Empty recycling bin from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/105530/empty-recycling-bin-from-command-line)

(If nothing helps I'll try delage32)

Comment: Don't see why recycler would work -- the recycle bin has not been a "Recycler" folder on the drive since the Win9x days.

Comment: @Billy: Yes it has, it's just that now, it's a System + Hidden folder, plus in Windows Vista/7 it's been changed to being called `$Recycle.Bin`.

Comment: There are several utilities out there that do this. Are you open to downloading one of these and running it from your batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `rmdir /q /s C:\Recycler` on Windows XP, and a similar one for Windows 7 with `$Recycle.Bin`. In the latter, you must be running as Administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you actually can limit this to a specific drive. The recycle bin itself is not provided as a part of the system itself; rather it is provided as a convenience by the Shell. At least as far as I am aware, it is drive/device agnostic.

You can use [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) with the command `nircmd emptybin` to empty the recycle bin, but emptying the recycle bin does so on all drives.